# Header image does not take full space within header

Tags: html, css, image

Looking for some help please. I am looking to have this image take up the full size of the header area on a site I am developing.

HTML

```
    <header>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="image_header">
             <img src="banner.jpg" alt="Property Homepage Logo">
    </div>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper
{margin: 0 auto;
width: 80%;}
.header
{display: flex;
background-color: #4f6367; 
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}
.image_header
{
display: flex;
object-fit: fill;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I have tried multiple approaches to no avail, hence looking for guidance here. I have tried max-width, width, different content settings none have successfully altered the image to take up the entire header area. Thanks in advance. *Edited to add current HTML and CSS code

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Can you please add your HTML so we can fix your problem if you only got css but not accurate HTML it might not fix your problem.

Comment: Pls provide HTML code in a minimale reproducible snippet